# How To change Position Of category Using Query in magento2?

Tags: magento2, category, jquery, position

How To change Position Of category Using Query in magento2 ?

->Magento@ admin Side Default category Position change Drag and Drop Through. But but i have to use it code for the changing  postion of category?

Comment: please explain briefly